# Relationships: Ember data & MySQL

Tags: mysql, ember.js, ember-data, relationships

Hei guys,

I would like to understand how to connect MySQL and Ember data relationships.

For example, i have a user model:

```
// app/models/user.js

export default({
  collections: hasMany('collection')
});


// app/models/collection.js:

export default({
  user: belongsTo('user')
});
```

This part is very simple, i get it.

Now, the problem: How should i express the relationship in the MySQL? Using the same names (columns) to add foreign keys?

Thanks in advance1

Comment: What do you want for your user table? What analogy have you already seen online? Your question is beyond vague.

Answer (score 0):

Ember doesn't care what database you use, because it doesn't talk to the database. The recommended way to move data between Ember and your server is using [JSON-API](http://jsonapi.org/), a specification for building REST APIs. All your sever needs to do is speak JSON-API and it should work with your Ember application.

To use JSON-API add the following to your Ember application:

`app/adapters/application.js`

```
import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api';

export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({});
```